# HTML/CSS - Scrollable section does not fit to the page.

Tags: html, css

I have a web application, which I did not develop myself, but am tasked with cleaning up a few things that are no longer working.

There is one issue that I am not really able to figure out why it is happening.

The web application is split into two panels. However, the second panel which is scrollable does not reach the bottom of the page, when a user scrolls all the way down.

Also by zooming out (ctrl -) we get a blank area at the bottom, although the panel can continue scrolling.

Id like to have this panel, scroll as if it was the full page.

Ive put a quick static copy up on fiddle at.

https://jsfiddle.net/brianz820/qmzw8923/

The section in question I believe is.

```
<div id="house-estimates-scroll-panel">
    <div id="house-estimates-listing"></div>
</div>

div#house-estimates-scroll-panel {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 1200px;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    overflow-y: visible ;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f3f3f3 , #bbb);
    background-size: 15px 20px;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;

}

div#house-estimates-listing {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 90000px;
    /*width: 320px;*/
    /*width: 960px;*/
}
```

Ive added the full HTML and CSS sections to the fiddle.

Comment: interesting problem you have there.  Is `flex-box` OK to use?

Comment: We only need to run in firefox maybe ever chrome.. so ye. Ive tried a lot of refactoring but nothing with flex yet, nor am I too keen on a lot of css tricks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try making the wrapper into a `display:flex` container by adding these rules (some look weird because of specificity issues)

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div#wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#house-estimates-panel {
  display:flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#house-estimates-scroll-panel{
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
}

div#house-estimates-listing {
  height: auto;
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gw35wc4c/1/show/
source (my css is at the bottom): https://jsfiddle.net/gw35wc4c/1/

Comment: This should work in firefox right? Everything looks fine in chrome but firefox does not scroll

Comment: @Busturdust Hm... I see that. It should be working. The issue is the height of that `#house-estimates-panel`.  It's not conforming to the flexbox wrapper.  I'll see what I can figure out

Comment: I tried adding a `* {min-height: 0}` which did work, but added a lot of jerkiness to the page

Comment: @Busturdust I've revised my code.  It was issue with the `div#house-estimates-panel` not having `overflow:hidden`.  That should be closer to what you were after.  Unfortunately one thing I noticed is that the left panel is not visible if you have a short browser/viewport.  Not sure if that's an issue or not.  I also think jankiness might be inevitable.  That's a very tall panel forced into a scrolling overflow.

Comment: that change works, and I will close this topic as I have achieved scrollability. I do need to see if I can resolve this jankiness though, jumps around too much. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: FYI: it looks like adding `overflow-y: scroll` to `house-estimates-scroll-panel` relieves the jankiness!!!! thanks agai